# SUMIF for multiple spreadsheets with text conditional

Tags: excel

I have an Excel book with around 100 spreadsheets within the book. Each spreadsheet is an application of certain products. The very last spreadsheet is a total tally for the year for each product we use.  The `SUMIF` formula I am using is:

```
=SUMIF('Jan 1:Dec 31'!B5:B14,"Name of product",'Jan 1:Dec 31'!D5:D14)
```

So when the Name of the product is used in `B5:B14` in all spreadsheets from first (Jan 1) to last (Dec 31) I want to sum its value from the `D5:D14` cells in all spreadsheets from first (Jan 1) to last (Dec 31).

The problem is that I just end up getting a `#VALUE` error. I have also tried inputting the formula by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: 3d references (references across multiple worksheets) don't work in SUMIF, so you need a different approach - are there 100 worksheets or 365 (one for every day)?

Comment: Ok I didn't know that.  I will have over 100 spreadsheets but not one for each day in the year.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `indirect` formula and have `Jan 1` in cell `A1`, and then in `B1` have formula:

```
= sumif(indirect(A1&"!B5:B14"),"Name of product",indirect(A1&"!D5:D14"))
```

Then you'd put `Jan 2` in cell `B1` and copy the `sumif` formula down.

Note that this assumes structure is consistent on each tab and that number of rows is consistent on each tab as well (or you can make the bottom of the range an arbitrarily high number like row 50,000)

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself.  The spreadsheet names are labeled Jan 1 through Dec 31. 

In the totals spreadsheet I only want one cell giving the sum of each product for that year.

Comment: Only alternative I can think of is to just have `sumif` on each tab (you can highlight multiple tabs and enter the `sumif` formula in an empty cell to save time), and then do a simple `sum` across the different worksheets, the result of which will be in only a single cell on your summary tab

Comment: If you can list all the sheet names and call that `SheetList` then you can use a similar approach with a single formula, i.e. `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!B5:B14"),"Name of product",INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!D5:D14")))`

Comment: @barryhoudini has the best way to do this in my opinion, it'll still require typing a list of the tab names somewhere though

Comment: If all the sheet names are of the form `"mmm d"`, e.g. Nov 20, Dec 8 etc then this version constructs the sheet names within the formula so you don't need a list (using IFERROR to return zero when sheets for that specific date don't exist) - `=SUM(IFERROR(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:366")),"mmm d")&"'!B5:B14"),"Name of Product",INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:366")),"mmm d")&"'!D5:D14")),0))` this version requires "array entry" with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER